# left outer join in BAL using repository pattern - null exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I don't quite understand why the following syntax, runs fine directly to Entity Framework.

```
var query = (from c in entitites.car
             join cat in entitites.categories on c.code equals cat.code into categoriesGroup
             from cg in categoriesGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

             select new CarListModel
             {
                 Car = c,            
                 CategoryDescription = cg == null ? null : cg.Description
             });

var test = query.ToList(); //Success
```

While doing the same query on iqueryables from my repository fails with "The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive, enumeration or reference type." The repository uses the same entities object.

```
var queryCars = carRepository.GetIQueryable();
var queryCategory = categoryRepository.GetIQueryable();

var query = (from c in queryCars
             join cat in queryCategory on c.Code equals cat.Code into categories
             from cg in categories.DefaultIfEmpty()

             select new CarListModel
             {
                 Car = c,            
                 CategoryDescription = cg == null ? null : cg.Description
             });

var test = query.ToList(); // Fails!!!
```

Using the repository pattern, it does work if I change the syntax to

```
...
CategoryDescription = cg.Description
```

But if I mock up the repositories from List it failes with Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I believe this has something do to with materialized / non-materialized data.

The .DefaultIfEmpty clearly returns a different result in these examples, and I was thinking of overriding with always returning NULL if empty. Not sure how I would go about this either.

The idea is to isolate the business logic to a service layer, and not in the repository. Though perhaps joining tables is "not" BL, and is fine in repository? How to do complex joins using this pattern?

Is is it not possible to do IQueryable joins using the repositories?

**Update!**
Added an example of the GetIQueryable method from the repository

```
public class Category
{
  Public string Code {get;set;}
  Public string Description {get; set;}
}

public IQueryable<Category> GetIQueryable()
    {
        return (from c in entities.categories
                select new Category
                {
                    Code = c.code,
                    Description = c.descripton

                }).AsQueryable();
    }
```

Comment: Show `GetIQueryable` method

Comment: I forgot that one, ...added an example of it now

Comment: In `GetIQueryable`: Why not simply `return entities.categories;`? What is `Category` class there? And what EF are you using? EF6 does not allow projecting to entity class. Smells like EF Core.

Comment: I am using EF5. The reason for the Category class is for mapping EF objects to POCO. The repository is an interface, to support testing with mock repositories

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetIQueryable()
{
    return (from c in entities.categories
            select new Category
            {
                Code = c.code,
                Description = c.descripton

            }).AsQueryable();
}
```

You can't use `new Category` in query, because `Category` is your data model class (mapped to table). You have 2 options:

1. Rewrite query without `new`:

   ```
   public IQueryable<Category>GetIQueryable()
   {
       return (from c in entities.categories
               select c).AsQueryable();
   }
   ```
2. Use another DTO objects as result:

   ```
   class CategoryDto
   {
       public int Code {get;set;}
       public string Description {get;set;}
   }

   //...

   public IQueryable<CategoryDto> GetIQueryable()
   {
       return (from c in entities.categories
               select new CategoryDto
               {
                   Code = c.code,
                   Description = c.descripton
               }).AsQueryable();
   }
   ```

Comment: Category is not the data model class. It's category.The method 1 would return the entity object 'category', not the poco object Category. I think that method 2 is actually what I am using. Category is the DTO object (poco with no relation to ef).